# separate currency numbers by comma in exported pdfs of stimulsoft

Tags: pdf, report, stimulsoft, currency-formatting

I have a report containing a currency text filed. I want to separate it's number by coma, every 3 digits. so I changed it's Text Format from it's Properties.
It's OK in normal display, but when I export this report to a PDF file, then it's currency numbers doesn't display well.
Please help me about this problem.

Comment: What product do you use? Version?

Comment: Stimulsoft Reports.Net
Version 2012.2.1304 from 4 May 2012

Comment: At first you should upgrade to the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formats.
For example you can fill your text field with:

Price is: {Format("{0:C}", MyPrice)}